# Gnome Shell related JS errors seen in syslog file during investigating system freeze

Tags: freeze, system, syslog

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (upgraded from original install of 18.04.4 LTS) on an HP Eitebook 2560 Intel Core i5

Trying to investigate a system issue where the UI became unresponsive at the lock screen. Finding lots of the following errors in the `/var/log/syslog` file around the time when it became unresponsive.

```
May  7 12:31:00 hp-ubuntu gnome-shell[2046]: JS ERROR: TypeError: windowActor is null#012_addWindowEffect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:90:28#012vfunc_show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:162:14

May  7 12:31:13 hp-ubuntu gnome-shell[2046]: message repeated 13988 times: [ JS ERROR: TypeError: null has no properties#012_onFocusChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:135:9#012_setTransitionProgress@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/unlockDialog.js:715:9#012_init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/unlockDialog.js:494:18]
```

Comment: You've probably got a GNOME Shell extension problem. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable ALL extensions, restart GNOME Shell with alt+f2, then r, then enter. Retest. Re-enable one extension at a time until you figure out which one it is.

Comment: ['desktop-icons@csoriano',  'ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com',  'ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com'] . 0, 1 or 2. Which one heynnema ? desktop icon, app indicator or the menu. Can you be more specific then the entire universe ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing more or less the same thing. Same errors and serious delay navigating different windows and workspace screens

Answer (score 1):

journalctl

[image]

```
cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf
```

Can turn off logging to journald to get back some use of your machine until locate and fix the bug that is crashing your machine. Original value was to accept thousands per a second, the screen shot is changed to accept  0 per 0 seconds.
[image]

```
FileName='/etc/systemd/journald.conf'


FindLine='#RateLimitIntervalSec='
ReplaceWith='#RateLimitIntervalSec=0s'
sudo sed -i "/$FindLine/c\$ReplaceWith" $FileName

FindLine='#RateLimitBurst='
ReplaceWith='RateLimitBurst=0'
sudo sed -i "/$FindLine/c\$ReplaceWith" $FileName


cat $FileName | grep --color -E "^|$FindLine"
```