# My system it's slow and keep freezing

Tags: boot, 20.04, bootloader, system

## Issue

### Slow System

When I log into the system it takes quite some time to "get ready" for use. When I open applications like `File System` takes a long time to open them.

### Frozen Screen(s)

In three days that I used this system, the computer froze more than 4 times.
The screens froze but the system keeps running (tested during a zoom call where the camera and microphone kept working after the incident).

Every time the system freezes the only solution is rebooting with `Alt` + `SystemKeyit` + `R E I S U B`. No other key combinations works (I tried `Alt` + `F2` and any other function key)

## What I tried

I tried reinstalling the OS (still Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

## System

### hardware

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800XT 3.9 GHz 8-Core
- Motherboard MSI B550-A PRO (BIOS: A.10)
- Ram: 32GB (4x8GB) 3600
- SSD: 512GB M.2-2280
- HDD: 3TB 7200RPM
- Video Card: MSI Radeon RX 5500 XT 8GB (2 monitors connected)

### Operative System

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

#### Partitions

- EFI: 500MB (SSD)
- Swap: 38GB (SSD)
- /boot: 500MB (SSD)
- root: 473GB (SSD)
- /home: 3TB (HDD)

#### What's on it

I have just built this System and freshly installed Ubuntu on it.
The only applications on the system currently are:

- Default applications installed with 'Normal Installation'
- Zoom.us client
- gphoto2 to connect my camera as a webcam
- Virtual box with 2 virtual machines
- Telegram

## Edits

In the log file there is a persistent error:

```
Nov 27 00:08:45 chale-MS gnome-shell[2441]: JS ERROR: TypeError: windowActor is null#012_addWindowEffect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:90:28#012vfunc_show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:162:14
```

Other errors in the log file on latest reboot (after installing the drivers for the video card)

```
gnome-shell[1948]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation

colord[1089]: failed to get session [pid 2140]: No data available

gnome-shell[1308]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 68 failed: Permission denied

gsd-color[2140]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Dell_Inc__DELL_U2717D_J0XYN655A7MS_gdm_125

fwupd[2413]: 19:09:31:0182 FuPluginUefi         Error opening directory “/sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries”: No such file or directory

tracker-miner-f[1240]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
```

running `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
returns:

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 lug 31 18:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 nov 25 19:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 nov 25 19:41 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 lug 31 18:29 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 nov 25 19:40 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

running `free -h`
returns:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       4,6Gi        22Gi       201Mi       4,2Gi        26Gi
Swap:          30Gi          0B        30Gi
```

running `sudo lshw -C memory` 
returns:

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A.10
       date: 07/01/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M4D3600C18
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M4D3600C18
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M4D3600C18
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M4D3600C18
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 14
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 32MiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Screenshot of Smart data HDD:
[image]

`memtest` report:
[image]

Comment: Anything [in your logs](https://superuser.com/questions/347222/how-to-check-ubuntu-crash-log-in-last-session) give you any indication of the error?

Comment: @DankyNanky What in particular should I look for?

Comment: I found an error in the log directory and updated in the question

Comment: For example, `more /var/log/syslog | grep crash` may return items. You could follow [DebuggingSytemCrash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash) guides as well. Further, you can look at `/var/crash` (found this loosely mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068720/what-can-i-do-to-find-the-crash-reason)). Once there is context we can try to help.

Comment: Please let us know [if this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237070/gnome-shell-related-js-errors-seen-in-syslog-file-during-investigating-system-fr) helps you. Quick run-around stipulates there seem to be issues with some GNOME Extensions, but I am unsure how to help on this one. (There do appear to be [slightly related](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3006) bug reports on this that have been logged as well). I am sure one of the gurus here will help out.

Comment: @DankyNanky I read that question but don't really understand what the answer is explaining to do. Since is not been marked as solved I don't feel confident about changing configurations that may not solve the issue ^^'

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application **SMART Data** scrollable window. Also see my answer for more info requests.

Comment: @heynnema I added the changes. It doesn't let me see Smart data for the SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hardware:

Everything  with the hardware is fine.

### Partitions:

the partitions should be:

- EFI: 1024MB (SSD)
- Swap: 38GB (with hibernation)
- root: 473GB (SSD)
- /home: 3TB (HDD)

### Solution:

To fix the computer from stop freezing and being slow an upgrade of the kernel did the job. in my case I update it to the last signed update: `5.8.0-33~20.04.1`

```bsh
sudo apt install linux-image-5.8.0-33-generic 
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-33-generic
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.8.0-33-generic
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-33-generic
```

and rebooted the system

```
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

**BIOS**

MSI B550-A PRO

You have BIOS: A.10

There's a newer BIOS available, version A4, and can be downloaded at [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B550-A-PRO). There IS a newer BIOS available, version A51, but it's a beta, so I wouldn't install it now.

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backup before updating the BIOS.

**memory/swap**

Your swap partition is excessive, and a fresh install of 20.04 prefers a /swapfile instead of a swap partition. Your root partition is also excessive.

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues.

See [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B550-A-PRO#support-cpu) and determine your processor family type, and then check the memory lists to verify that your current memory DIMMs are supported.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Radeon RX 5500 XT**

The Linux driver for this is found [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-xt).

[image]

Comment: I'e updated the question with the infos. I am going to try to update the BIOS and try to run `memtest`. In regards to the swap and root partition are excessive, I've search around the internet and found different guides. most of them sayed that I should have my swap partition double my ram but I followed a chart that showed that for 32GB ram it was enough 38GB (with hibernation, I'm not sure if I am going to use it but I left the chance). What would you recomend? is there a guide I can follow?

Comment: Checking on the link you gave me I can't find my memory ram in the list under 'Matisse' nor in any other family. What does that mean? and what should I do?

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro  Thanks for the info. You forgot `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. The swap is ok if you're going to hibernate. If the memory isn't in any of the lists, run the `memtest` and let's see if it finds any problem. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: Thank you for your support, `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` returns: "No such file or directory". My CPU and RAM are not yet overclocked, I didn't know if it was needed and guessed that is something I'll be able to do later on.

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro Report back after the BIOS update and `memtest`.

Comment: No error from `memtest` and BIOS updated

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro Do you have the latest video drivers for your MSI Radeon RX 5500 XT? I've run out of ideas for you. Sorry.

Comment: I was trying to install the drivers for ubuntu but on the MSI's website only shows Windows ones.

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro See the update in my answer.

Comment: After installing the driver, how can I be able to see if there are any error? does the log file reports the last session or the life time of the system?

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro /var/log/syslog and /var/log/syslog.1 will show you approx the last 2 days.

Comment: is it normal that after rebooting the system the login screens appear pretty quickly but after inserting the password it gives me a black screen for about 30sec before being able to see the Desktop?

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro No, that's not normal. Log into a different account and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro Status please...

Comment: I reinstall the OS once again an manage to fix the speed issue. I still experienced the freezing issue and I am currently waiting for the new (supported) ram to replace.

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro Don't you have Corsair RAM now? And it passed `memtest`, yes? I don't know if I'd replace RAM yet. You can remove DIMMs, two at a time, to eliminate a RAM issue.